# How to access custom environments in package examples in R

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I have an R package in which I define a custom environment at package load using the .onLoad() function. This works fine but, when I document the function using rxoygen2 and do devtools::check(), if there is any reference to a function that that uses this environment, check() throws an error because it can't find the environment.

For example, a package with a single R file:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
    set_my_env()
}

#' Sets my environment
set_my_env <- function(){
    message("Setting my environment")
    .my_env <<- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
    .my_env$variable <- "My variable"

}

#' my_fn function
#' @examples my_fn()
my_fn <- function(){
    get("variable", envir = .my_env)
}
```

when I call devtools::check() on the package, I get:

```
* checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in ‘mypackage-Ex.R’ failed
The error most likely occurred in:

> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
> ### Name: my_fn
> ### Title: my_fn function
> ### Aliases: my_fn
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> my_fn()
Error in get("variable", envir = .my_env) : object '.my_env' not found
Calls: my_fn -> get
Execution halted
```

If I remove the examples line from the roxygen2 documentation, the package builds fine.

My package relies on this environment and I don't want to just wrap all of my examples in \dontrun{}.  How can I get the examples to see this environment? The dot before the environment name does not make a difference here.

Comment: Why are you creating the environment at `.onLoad` as opposed to just creating an environment in your package namespace (and possibly not exporting it)?

Comment: It just seems cleaner - see http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/r.html (When you do need side effects).  Plus, if you remove the .onLoad function and put in a call to set_my_env() at the top level of the script, you get the same error when you run check().  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Its not devtools or roxygen2 fault, I get the same error running R CMD check at the command line.

Comment: I suspect examples run from (base) check are somehow "sandboxed" from the users workspace. It might be something like the "local=TRUE" arg to the `examples` function. The check code that runs examples is a twisty turny maze of passages, all alike... Might have to ask R-dev...

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the case. Seems odd to sandbox from the enclosing package though. My current ugly workaround is to just put the set_my_env() function at the start of every examples block...